# Prevent custom taxonomy from appearing in default post type?

Tags: wordpress

I've created a custom post type called "Merchants", and I have created a custom Taxonomy called "Company".

Within my custom post_type, I have the following:

```
'taxonomies'          => array('company'),
```

So now my taxonomy of Company is appearing in my Merchant post type which is great.  However for some reason, my custom taxonomy is showing up in the default post_type of "Post"

Is there anyway for me to stop this from appearing?

Comment: What does your `register_taxonomy` call look like?

Comment: register_taxonomy( 'company', array( 'post' ), $args );

Comment: Well, there's your issue.. you are associating the taxonomy via the second arg, `array( 'post' )`.

Comment: I thought that was to say the post type it was to be assigned to, either a post or a page for example.  My custom post_type is a post

Comment: Correct.. the `post_type`. Which in your case is `merchants` (or something similar). `page` is actually just an internal custom post. You don't create "custom page types", because it doesn't exist. So, you have two choices.. either you use an empty array during your register_taxonomy call and continue to assign the taxonomy in your custom post type definition like you have done already, or, you can leave off the `taxonomies` in your post type definition, and use `array('merchants')` when you define your taxonomy.